# Searching for keyword with grep in file content with newline without using regular expression

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way for me to perform the grep command such that:

This is a keyword to find "Subject: This is a keyword"

In the file, these could be the possible outcomes

Subject: This is a\n
keyword

Subject: This is\n
a keyword

Subject: This\n
is a keyword

I do not know how many variations are there.
Is there a way to use grep to match all of these scenarios without regex?

Otherwise, worse case I will have to copy all contents to another file, take all the new line away and concatenate then grep it.

Comment: why don't you want to use regexes?

Comment: for multiline search, you'd need grep variants like pcregrep, ripgrep, etc.. or you could use awk.. but why do you mention doing this task without regex?

Comment: i will try to explore other grep variants or awk. I just need a simple function to solve a simple problem. Once input into the function, be it awk , pcregrep, ripgrep("keyword", "filename") it should give me a match. I dont want to go inside regex cos no.1 we are not regex experts, 2. there are too many variants of the keyword, if i have to search the file for 10 keywords, there will be too many variants for the regex

Answer (score 0):

Here I used two other simple utilities to format the file so it can be grepped without using regular expressions.

> Note that new temporary newlines always start with "Subject: .." in this scenario, so grep's output may contain the rest of the line until the next "Subject: ..".

Sample input file:

```
Subject: This is a
 keyword
Sample text here-
Subject: This is
 a keyword
Another text here
Subject: This
 is a keyword
Ending line!
```

**Command:**

```
cat test.txt | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/Subject: /\n&/g' | grep 'Subject: This is a keyword'
```

*Sample output:*

```
Subject: This is a keywordSample text here-
Subject: This is a keywordAnother text here
Subject: This is a keywordEnding line!
```

> Note that if newline may happen even in the word 'Subject: ', the command would have to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tr` to convert the newlines `\n` to NUL characters `\0` and `grep` for optional NUL characters before the space character.

Using the sample input file from [user12938074](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60579249/10931455):

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < test.txt | grep -aPo 'Subject: This\0? is\0? a\0? keyword'
Subject: This is a  keyword
Subject: This is  a keyword
Subject: This  is a keyword
```

If needed, you can convert the NUL characters in your matches back to newlines

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < test.txt | grep -aPo 'Subject: This\0? is\0? a\0? keyword' | tr '\0' '\n'
Subject: This is a
 keyword
Subject: This is
 a keyword
Subject: This
 is a keyword
```

or delete the NUL characters

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < test.txt | grep -aPo 'Subject: This\0? is\0? a\0? keyword' | tr -d '\0'
Subject: This is a keyword
Subject: This is a keyword
Subject: This is a keyword
```

Options:

- `-a` treat binary input file as text
- `-P` enable Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE)
- `-o` print only matching parts